# Error in utils::browseURL when using esquisse as part of Shiny

Tags: r, url, browser, shiny, shinydashboard

I'm getting the following error continuously when using "export PNG" functionality of "esquisse" package as part of my Shiny app.

**"Error in utils::browseURL: 'browser' must be a non-empty character string"**

Had anyone met similar problem?

Thank you,
Kari

Comment: are you opening the Shiny app in your browser or just from RStudio?

Comment: I tried both. And I think I have found a solution. But it required tweaking esquisse package. I have updated the following line in esquisserServer function:  "utils::browseURL(url = tmp)". I added browser=NULL: "utils::browseURL(url = tmp, browser=NULL)"